# Logcat Error: App Crashes and does not run. Error at setContentView as per Logcat

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-debug

I'm developing a basic equation balancing app and am new to android dev. The app does not run on the phone at all. I had a splash screen as launcher previously and that used to pop and the app would shut off after that. I removed the Splash Screen and now the app won't open. I'm guessing there is an error in MainActivity (the splash screen used to intent to it and now it is the launcher activity). But on running the logcat alongside ADB emulation, it shows error in onCreate method of MainActivity. There are some more errors in logcat but I don't know what they mean(I guess the only error that matters is the onCreate one with a blue underline). Please Please do Help.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DialogCloseListener {

    private RecyclerView taskRecyclerView;
    private EqBalAdapter tasksAdapter;
    private List<EqBalModel> taskList;
    private DatabaseHandler db;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;
    private FloatingActionButton fab2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActionBar bar = getActionBar();

        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#00d024")));

        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_bottom);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.nav_home:
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_aboutus:
                        Intent a = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutUs.class);
                        startActivity(a);
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_help:
                        Intent b = new Intent(MainActivity.this,HelpGuide.class);
                        startActivity(b);
                        break;

                }
                return false;
            }
        });


        db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        db.openDatabase();

        taskList = new ArrayList<>();

        taskRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.reacRecyclerView);
        taskRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        tasksAdapter = new EqBalAdapter(db, this);
        taskRecyclerView.setAdapter(tasksAdapter);

        fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);

        ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new
                ItemTouchHelper(new RecyclerItemTouchHelper(tasksAdapter));
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(taskRecyclerView);

        taskList = db.getAllTasks();
        Collections.reverse(taskList);
        tasksAdapter.setTasks(taskList);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AddNewTask.newInstance().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), AddNewTask.TAG);
            }
        });
        fab2=findViewById(R.id.newactivity);

        ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper2 = new
                ItemTouchHelper(new RecyclerItemTouchHelper(tasksAdapter));
        itemTouchHelper2.attachToRecyclerView(taskRecyclerView);


        fab2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, eleView.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void handleDialogClose(DialogInterface dialog) {
        taskList = db.getAllTasks();
        Collections.reverse(taskList);
        tasksAdapter.setTasks(taskList);
        tasksAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ReactantText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="Equation Balancer"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="32dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/reacRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/ReactantText"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="183dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/newactivity"
        android:layout_width="86dp"
        android:layout_height="82dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="34dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="97dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_elements" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/nav_bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/black"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidMainfest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.chemicalequationbalancer">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ChemicalEquationBalancer">


        <activity android:name="com.example.chemicalequationbalancer.AboutUs" android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"/>
        <activity android:name="com.example.chemicalequationbalancer.HelpGuide" android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"/>
        <activity android:name="com.example.chemicalequationbalancer.eleView" android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"/>


        <activity
            android:name="com.example.chemicalequationbalancer.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.ChemicalEquationBalancer.ActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

build.gradle(app):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.chemicalequationbalancer">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ChemicalEquationBalancer">


        <activity android:name="com.example.chemicalequationbalancer.AboutUs" android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"/>
        <activity android:name="com.example.chemicalequationbalancer.HelpGuide" android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"/>
        <activity android:name="com.example.chemicalequationbalancer.eleView" android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"/>


        <activity
            android:name="com.example.chemicalequationbalancer.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.ChemicalEquationBalancer.ActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

**Logcat**
Here's the underlined line in logcat: `com.example.chemicalequationbalancer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51)`

```
2021-02-16 02:07:50.712 13502-13502/com.example.chemicalequationbalancer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.chemicalequationbalancer, PID: 13502
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.chemicalequationbalancer/com.example.chemicalequationbalancer.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3197)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3334)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:113)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:71)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2025)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:226)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7191)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:499)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:942)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:652)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:817)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:740)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:890)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:851)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onResourcesLoaded(DecorView.java:2239)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2761)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2868)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:2133)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.initViewTreeOwners(AppCompatActivity.java:198)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:173)
        at **com.example.chemicalequationbalancer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:51)**
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7376)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7367)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3177)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3334)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:113)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:71)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2025)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:226)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7191)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:499)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:942)
2021-02-16 02:07:50.714 13502-13502/com.example.chemicalequationbalancer E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 13: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x1010433 a=1}
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:946)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:930)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5108)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:665)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:92)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:87)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:82)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(ActionBarContainer.java:61)
            ... 32 more
```

If any other files are needed, I am ready to provide. I just want to know what is happening and sort it out. Thanks!

PS: [Which of these is the folder which actually gets converted to apk? Is it main folder, the chemicalequationbalancer?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUrx4.png)

EDIT:
themes.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.ChemicalEquationBalancer" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.ChemicalEquationBalancer.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.ChemicalEquationBalancer.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="Theme.ChemicalEquationBalancer.ActionBar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.ChemicalEquationBalancer.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    <style name="DialogStyle" parent="Theme.Design.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Please show us your theme named  **Theme.ChemicalEquationBalancer.ActionBar**

Comment: @SarahKhan Here's it: `<style name="Theme.ChemicalEquationBalancer.ActionBar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
    </style>`  I've edited the original post with the entire themes.xml just incase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MainActivity is extending AppCompatActivity which means it inherits the default action bar.

> ThemeOverlay.AppCompat(parent for
> Theme.ChemicalEquationBalancer.ActionBar)  is used to override (or
> “overlay”) that theme for specific views, especially the Toolbar.

If you want to customize this ActionBar (you are probably doing that), you add one of the NoActionBar themes in your activity's manifest and then supply a toolbar to your activity's layout.

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.chemicalequationbalancer.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Light.NoActionBar" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

In your activity_main.xml, you can add whatever theme you want

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    ...
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.ChemicalEquationBalancer.ActionBar />
```

And not in the manifest file

Comment: Thank you so so much! Really Appreciated!! This solved that error and same error which occurred in other files for the same reason. There is another error however in another activity for BottomNavigation. Again Logcat shows its an error but no "error" found. Here's the line: `BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_bottom);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() ` Thanks really really thanks for all the help. You are the hero we needed.

Comment: Can you please upvote and mark this as your answer?

Comment: And please post the other issue as a separate question so we could have a look at it?

Comment: I've added the question as a new post and also marked your answer. When I upvote your answer, it says upvotes by accounts less than 15 reputation are recorded but they don't change public upvote count :( Sorry

Comment: I can actually upvote now! Upvoted your answer!