# App crashes when a CustomNoActionBar style is used for an activity

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I click on a Floating Action Button that is in the main activity and when i click it, i am supposed to be in the second activity but the app crashes when i click the floating action button. The logcat was pointing to this code that was crashing the app:

**setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_happy_place)**

The above line which is in the onCreate method of my second activity was crashing the app. So I spent a lot of time and found out that in the AndroidManifest.xml file, the style of my second activity has a custom theme and when i removed that one line then the app wasn't crashing anymore.

Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.happyplaces">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.HappyPlaces">
    <activity
        android:name=".AddHappyPlaceActivity"
        android:label="ADD HAPPY PLACE"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

CustomNoActionBarTheme:

```
<style name="CustomNoActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

If i don't use the CustomActionBarTheme then the app doesn't crash but i want it to work because i dont need an ActionBar for that activity. How can i fix this? Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Logcat of the crash:

```
    20  21-05-07 11:01:00.164 1909-1909/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
20  21-05-07 11:01:00.675 2267-2267/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.happyplaces, PID: 2267
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.happyplaces/com.example.happyplaces.AddHappyPlaceActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36 in com.example.happyplaces:layout/activity_add_happy_place: Binary XML file line #36 in com.example.happyplaces:layout/activity_add_happy_place: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36 in com.example.happyplaces:layout/activity_add_happy_place: Binary XML file line #36 in com.example.happyplaces:layout/activity_add_happy_place: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36 in com.example.happyplaces:layout/activity_add_happy_place: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:854)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1006)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1126)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1126)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
at com.example.happyplaces.AddHappyPlaceActivity.onCreate(AddHappyPlaceActivity.kt:13)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
2021-05-07 11:01:00.675 2267-2267/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:243)
at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkMaterialTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:217)
at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.checkCompatibleTheme(ThemeEnforcement.java:145)
at com.google.android.material.internal.ThemeEnforcement.obtainTintedStyledAttributes(ThemeEnforcement.java:115)
at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:463)
at com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.<init>(TextInputLayout.java:422)
... 32 more
2021-05-07 11:01:00.804 2030-2126/? E/InputDispatcher: channel 'c3c4942 com.example.happyplaces/com.example.happyplaces.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

Main Activity Code:

```
package com.example.happyplaces

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    fabAddHappyPlace.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, AddHappyPlaceActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

Second Activity [AddHappyPlaceActivity] Code:

```
    package com.example.happyplaces


import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_add_happy_place.*

class AddHappyPlaceActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_happy_place)

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar_add_place)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

        toolbar_add_place.setNavigationOnClickListener {
            onBackPressed()
        }
    }
}
```

I have a toolbar in my second activity and it has a custom theme:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_add_place"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:theme="@style/CustomToolbarStyle"/>
```

CustomToolbarStyle:

```
<style name="CustomToolbarStyle">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlNormal">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

**Edit:**

I added a new style named Material Theme as answered by Shams. The app crashed again and this time the logcat pointed out to this line in the code of the second activity:

**setSupportActionBar(toolbar_add_place)**

The logcat:

```
    2021-05-07 12:36:16.373 6086-6086/? E/ple.happyplace: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2021-05-07 12:36:19.115 6086-6086/com.example.happyplaces E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.happyplaces, PID: 6086
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.happyplaces/com.example.happyplaces.AddHappyPlaceActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:572)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:159)
at com.example.happyplaces.AddHappyPlaceActivity.onCreate(AddHappyPlaceActivity.kt:15)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

I removed these lines of code in the second activity:

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar_add_place)
    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

    toolbar_add_place.setNavigationOnClickListener {
        onBackPressed()
    }
```

The toolbar was still in the xml file and the application didn't crash this time. But i obviously want the toolbar to have onBackPressed() which i am not able to do for now.

Comment: Could you share the logcat of the crash along with the code of each activity?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66215196/logcat-error-app-crashes-and-does-not-run-error-at-setcontentview-as-per-logca/66228040#66228040 Does this help?

Comment: @TheRyanKing87 Updated the question

Comment: @SarahKhan I checked the link that you shared and the app still crashes :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Error inflating class com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
```

Error occur when inflating TextInputLayout. Why? Because you are using `TextInputLayout` without inherit from  `Theme.MaterialComponents`. So you must inherit from `Theme.MaterialComponents`.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
```

First create material theme in style.xml

```
<style name="MaterialTheme" 
        parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar.Bridge">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

And use it in application tag in manifest

```
<application
    android:theme="@style/MaterialTheme"
```

or in specific activity

```
<activity
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name=".ui.HomeFragmentActivity"/>
```

Comment: Hey i tried what you said and it worked? but the app crashed again due to another reason. I updated about it in the question. Please check it out.

Comment: I created the theme like you said and even tho my app crashed due to the toolbar. I checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26515058/this-activity-already-has-an-action-bar-supplied-by-the-window-decor and now the app is working fine. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment so I'm leaving my comment as an answer.

Did you set the toolbar in the Layout?

For trouble shooting purposes you can try removing the appbar setup from the second activity to see if that is causing the problem.

Comment: I removed the toolbar in the second activity and the app still crashed. The app goes to the second activity only when i remove the code in the manifest where i set a CustomNoActionBarTheme.

Comment: Can you post the Manifest file?

Comment: Posted the Manifest file